# Can we use plain jdbc connection for spring transaction management

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc, connection-pool

I have plain jdbc connection pool in my project and using ejb for transaction. Now I want to change the transaction management to Spring transaction management
but, I don't want to create separate datasource for this, I want to use same plain connection pool.

Is it possible to do it?

Below is my spring bean for transaction(datasource is blank as I don't know how to set it from plain jdbc connection pool)

```
@Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public DataSourceTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
        DataSourceTransactionManager txManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager();

        // Get the connection from plain connection pool and set it in datasource

        return txManager;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a Bean under the Spring factory's control, so you can inject it.

Try this:

```
@Bean(name = "transactionManager")
public DataSourceTransactionManager getTransactionManager(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
}
```